Persistent AbortError During Reconnection Attempts in Discord Bot
I'm working on a Discord bot that connects to a voice channel, listens to the audio, and sends it to a WebSocket server. Initially, everything works fine, but after some time, when I try to reconnect after losing the connection, I encounter `AbortError` repeatedly. Despite several attempts to handle this error, the problem persists.  The error occurs during the reconnection attempts. Here is the error message I keep receiving:
Attempting to reconnect: Try 1 of 5Reconnect attempt 2 failed: AbortError: The operation was abortedat EventTarget.abortListener (node:events:1008:14)at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:822:20)at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:757:26)at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:374:10)at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:396:5)at Timeout.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:1931:39)at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {code: 'ABORT_ERR',[cause]: DOMException [AbortError]: This operation was abortedat new DOMException (node:internal/per_context/domexception:53:5)at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:395:18)at Timeout.<anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:1931:39)at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)}

Here are the key parts of the code I use to handle the connection and reconnection attempts:
1. Handling Connection and WebSocket:
let connection; let count = 0;  await entersState(connection, VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, 30000); console.log('Voice connection ready:', voiceChannel.id); let player = createAudioPlayer(); connection.subscribe(player);  let ws = new WebSocket('ws://...');  ws.on('open', () => {   console.log('WebSocket connection opened');   voiceChannel.members.forEach(member => {     if (member.user.id !== client.user.id) {       member.voice.setMute(false);     }   }); });  ws.on('error', (error) => {   console.error('WebSocket error:', error); });  ws.on('close', () => {   console.log('WebSocket connection closed, attempting to reconnect...');   reconnectWebSocket(ws); });


Reconnecting Logic:

async function attemptReconnect(client, voiceChannel, player, retries = 5, delay = 10000) {
  for (let i = 0; i < retries; i++) {
    try {
      console.log(`Attempting to reconnect: Try ${i + 1} of ${retries}`);
      connection.destroy();
      connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: voiceChannel.id,
        guildId: voiceChannel.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: voiceChannel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        selfDeaf: false,
        selfMute: false
      });

      await entersState(connection, VoiceConnectionStatus.Ready, 30000);
      console.log('Reconnected to voice channel:', voiceChannel.id);
      connection.subscribe(player);
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Reconnect attempt ${i + 1} failed:`, error);
      if (error.code === 'ABORT_ERR') {
        console.log('Reconnect attempt aborted, will retry');
      }
      if (i < retries - 1) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
        delay *= 2; // Increase delay exponentially
      }
    }
  }
  console.error('Failed to reconnect to voice channel after several attempts, restarting connection');
  restartConnection(client, voiceChannel);
}


Restarting Connection:

function restartConnection(client, voiceChannel) {
  try {
    if (connection) {
      connection.destroy();
      console.log('Connection destroyed');
    }
    handleAudio(client, voiceChannel);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error restarting connection:', error);
  }
}


Implement Exponential Retries: I have increased the delay between each reconnection attempt.
Destroy and Recreate Connections: Ensure the voice and WebSocket connections are destroyed before reconnecting.
Restart Complete Connection: After several failed attempts, I attempt to restart the entire connection.


What NodeJS version are you running? The latest stable version is recommended. Check using node -v.
